# Why i cannot use int value to control my icon color in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, setstate

I wanted to change my favicon whether pushing in it but it is not happening because I cannot use the int value to control it. Here is my code example=>

```
class _WebViewExampleState extends State<WebViewExample> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();
  int ctr=0;
...
 floatingActionButton: favoriteButton(),
...
Widget favoriteButton() {
    return FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
        future: _controller.future,
        builder: (BuildContext context,
            AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
          if (controller.hasData) {
            return FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
              onPressed: () async {
                final String url = (await controller.data!.currentUrl())!;
                // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  SnackBar(content: Text('Favorited $url')),
                );
                setState(() {
                  ctr++;
                });
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.favorite,
              <this place where i got the mistake> 
              color: this.ctr%2==1 ? Colors.red : Colors.white),
              </this place where i got the mistake>

            );
          }
          return Container();
        });
  }
}//end of the top row.
```

I mentioned the above as HTML tag "this place where I got the mistake". The mistake is **Invalid constant value** I also tried to declare the variable inside of favoriteButton.Why cannot use the variable to check conditions? Is anyone to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please remove const from icons widget

please check my code

```
child: Icon(Icons.favorite,
              <this place where i got the mistake> 
              color: this.ctr%2==1 ? Colors.red : Colors.white),
              </this place where i got the mistake>

            );
```

doing by that you can use mutable values

Comment: did you null checked this value  '' controller.data! '' , is there is a probability data should be null...?

Comment: it is about with const

Comment: not this is other question from my side .........